# Introductions to no-hair theorem(s)

Tags: black-holes, resource-recommendations

I wanted to ask if anyone can provide a reference that is an introduction on the [no-hair theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem)(s) (conjecture(s)). Review papers on the topic would be gratefully accepted as well.

I have already come across [1](http://cds.cern.ch/record/312731/files/9610019.pdf), [2](http://www.icra.it/MG/mg12/talks/anm4_beyer.pdf), and [3](http://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/theoreticalphysics/Public/MSc/Dissertations/2010/Wahiba%20Toubal%20Dissertation.pdf).

However, I am looking to gather more. I ask this question here because simply googling "no-hair theorem (conjecture)" pulls up far to many ArXiv papers proofing specific cases for particular spacetimes and under certain vacuum assumptions, and I am not interested in reading those at the moment (at a later date, yes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot I had asked this a while back, but I thought I would provide an answer since I have many references now. I realize that when I first asked this question I may have sounded a bit naive and I hadn't put much time into searching for references. Anyway, here are some references (old) related to no-hair theorems.

Older references: 
[1967](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.164.1776), [1968](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1968CMaPh...8..245I), [1971](http://luth.obspm.fr/~luthier/carter/trav/Carter71.pdf), [1971(2)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01877517), [1975](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.34.905).

I will add many more in a few hours or upon request.